# Herbert B. Enderton - Elements of set theory - Chapter 3 Relations and Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm currently reading Elements of set theory by Herbert B. Enderton, and at Chapter 3, Relations and Function, I am faced with this lemma and I am having a hard time understanding it.

**If $\langle x,y\rangle \in A$, then $x$ and $y$ belongs to $\bigcup\bigcup A$.**

**Proof:**

**We assume that $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} \in A$. Consequently, $\{x,y\} \in \bigcup A$ since it belongs to a member of $A$. And from this we conclude that $x\in \bigcup\bigcup A$ and $y \in \bigcup\bigcup A$.**

From what I understand $A$ is a set of ordered pairs of elements of $R$, that is, a subset of $R\times R$ and $\bigcup A $ should be the field($A$). I'm confused as to what $\bigcup\bigcup A$ is and how $x$ and $y$ would be a member of $\bigcup\bigcup A$. And shouldn't $x$ and $y$ both just be a member of $R\times R$?

Your explanation will be kindly appreciated. Thank you.

If you want to have a closer look at it : (Chapter 3.2, Lemma 3.16) http://p-adic.com/Set%20Theory.pdf

Comment: Where did $R$ come from? Neither the statement of the lemma nor its proof mention it.

Comment: I believe maxxxxx was referring to $A$ as a binary relation on some set $R$, but that is indeed confusing

Comment: It is not clear from this post what $UA$ and $UUA$ mean. Did you mean to write $\bigcup A$ and $\bigcup\bigcup A$?

Comment: Yes the R is mentioned as the set for the binary relation A. And so A would be the subset of the coordinate plane R x R. Very sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @John Douma Yes I meant ⋃A and ⋃⋃A. Sorry for the confusion, I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few points that hopefully provide some clarification.

$A$ isn't necessarily a relation on a set, as you assume. It might just happen to have an ordered pair in it. This fact will apply to relations, which only have ordered sets in them, but it doesn't require that.

The $\bigcup$ means union of a collection of sets, so $\bigcup A=\{x:x\in y\mbox{ for some }y\in A\}$.

In developing basic set theory where everything is a set, ordered pairs $(x,y)$ are defined as $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. (You don't want to think of an ordered pair as a different type of object, you want to think of it as a particular set that depends on the $x,y$ in the pair.)

So if $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\in A$, then the elements of that set are in $\bigcup A$. In particular, $\{x,y\}\in\bigcup A$.

Then if you look at $\bigcup\bigcup A$, this is repeating the definition above but instead of starting with $A$, you are starting with $\bigcup A$. And $x,y$ are elements of something (namely $\{x,y\}$) that is in $\bigcup A$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your explanation.